# user writes access path to a nested element in a JSON file

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I wrote a code that prompts the user for the access path to an element in a JSON file and then retrieves the value of that element. But I can only get access to a root element. What should user write to e.g. get object.array[2].field? I use single include nlohmann/json library.

My code:

```
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
std::ifstream file("test3.json");
json data;
file >> data;

std::string access_path;
std::cout << "Enter the access path to the nested element (e.g. 'object.array[2].field'): ";
std::getline(std::cin, access_path);

try {
    json nested_element = data.at(access_path);
    std::cout << "Value of element: " << nested_element.dump() << std::endl;
} catch (json::out_of_range& e) {
    std::cout << "Error: Invalid access path." << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It'd help if you showed the actual `test3.json` document too

Comment: To create a code block type ``` press enter paste code or json file as is from your editor and press enter then type ``` and press enter. No changes to the format are needed before the copy and paste.

Comment: IDK, but a quick look at the documentation and it seems the code should be `json nested_element = data.at(json_pointer(access_path));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need a [`json_pointer`](https://json.nlohmann.me/features/json_pointer/#introduction).

```cpp
json nested_element = data.at(json::json_pointer(access_path));
```

Then accessing `field` in `array[2]` in `object` would be entered by the user as

```
/object/array/2/field
```

Example version of the `test3.json` file:

```json
{
        "object": {
                "array": [{
                                "field": "foo"
                        },

                        {
                                "field": "bar"
                        },
                        {
                                "field": "hello world"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Value of element: "hello world"
```